# How do I play a flash animation in C?

Tags: c, flash

I'd like to play a flash animation (SWF) in plain C (win32). I'm currently using the "AtlAxWin" window class to play it, but it's not very suitable.

I'd appreciate any clues to directly use the flash player or even detect (in C) if the flash player is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio you could embed a web browser into your project and set the document text equal to some flash embed code. Make sure you have the SWF within the same folder as your EXE of course.

That would be the quick and dirty method.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend some helper libraries to do this such as [wxwidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) or [qt](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/).